LTS Release Upgrade aborted, now unclear state
my Ubuntu Release Upgrade aborted in unknown state. I started do-release-upgrade via ssh connection on my server. I tried to proceed after connection loss.
This is how it looks know. I am no pro, and have absolutely no clue what to do now.
Fresh install would take over one week. I can't do that.
Welcome to Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 6.8.0-1013-raspi aarch64)

 System information as of Thu Oct 31 12:15:31 CET 2024

  System load:           0.18
  Usage of /:            29.0% of 58.25GB
  Memory usage:          4%
  Swap usage:            0%
  Temperature:           47.7 C
  Processes:             161
  Users logged in:       0
  IPv4 address for eth0: 192.168.101.101
  IPv6 address for eth0: 2003:cb:cf0f:a36e:dea6:32ff:fed2:2c63

 * Strictly confined Kubernetes makes edge and IoT secure. Learn how MicroK8s
   just raised the bar for easy, resilient and secure K8s cluster deployment.

   https://ubuntu.com/engage/secure-kubernetes-at-the-edge

Expanded Security Maintenance for Applications is not enabled.

0 updates can be applied immediately.

Enable ESM Apps to receive additional future security updates.
See https://ubuntu.com/esm or run: sudo pro status

New release '24.04.1 LTS' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.

Last login: Thu Oct 31 12:09:33 2024 from 192.168.101.103

wolf@frida:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Release:    24.04
Codename:   noble
wolf@frida:~$ do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Failed to connect to https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts. Check your Internet connection or proxy settings
There is no development version of an LTS available.
To upgrade to the latest non-LTS development release 
set Prompt=normal in /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades.

What would you recommend?
The system now tells me there would be a new release. But I am not able to update anything anymore.

Please edit your question to show us the complete output of sudo apt update

It'd be helpful if specific with details; what were you running before you attempted the do-release-upgrade, as its best if you're specific rather than having us guess...  If it was me, I'd need to know what you were running, and expected to move to, inspect some files to see if it matches (log files will reveal what happened if you can't recall) and then as what @user535733 said (ie. apt update to see if what is shown matches what you'd expect (does it show new, or older release? etc; no mismatches in details etc)...  If I felt it looked good continue with sudo apt full-upgrade ...
